# Preloading images with js dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

This is really hard to explain, but i have a huge problem with preloading images that should be shown only on certain dropdown option.

I have tried to search on google and here, but i really couldn't find any solution, nor i understand this, as friend written it for me.

I will share the script (js) i'm using, and dropdown.

Images are being pulled out of database on dropdown (for each dropdown), and there are stored locally.

The problem is that, when user come to page, images are being preloaded in background and, if user in that time, click on dropdown option, image would not be shown. However, if he wait a bit (until all images are loaded (while they are loading, they are not visible on website)), and then select dropdown option, image will display just normally.

Here's script i have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.outtaHere').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('.countrylist').hide();
   $('.'+selected.val()).show();
    $('.optionvalue').html(selected.html());
});
});//]]>  

</script> 

<script>
function handleChange(input) 
 {
    if (input.value < 50) 
    {
       alert('Min value is: 50');
       input.value = 50;
     }

     if (input.value > 1000000) 
     {
       alert('Max value is: 100000');
         input.value = 1000000;
      }
 }
 </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 



var ids = new Array();
var use = new Array();
var ful = new Array();

ids[0] = "";
use[0] = "";
ful[0] = "";

<?php
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "ids[{$row["id"]}] = \"{$row["name"]}\";\n";
    echo "use[{$row["id"]}] = \"{$row["url"]}\";\n";
}
?>

        function Choice() {
            //x = document.getElementById("users");
            y = document.getElementById("selectUsers");

              //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
              document.getElementById("ids").value = ids[y.selectedIndex];
              document.getElementById("use").value = use[y.selectedIndex];
         }


//]]>  

</script>
```

And here's dropdown and div for displaying images:

```
  <select id="selectUsers" class=" outtaHere" name="users" onChange='Choice();'><option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
<?php
foreach($rows as $row){
echo "<option value=\"{$row["id"]}\">{$row["name"]}</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
</label>
<div style="margin-left: -20%;">
    <?php
foreach($rows as $row){
echo "  <ul class=\"countrylist {$row["id"]}\">\n";
echo "  <img src=\"{$row["thumb"]}\" class=\"vizitke\"/>\n";
echo "  </ul>\n";
 }
  ?>
</div>
```

Please understand my problem, i really tried my best to search for an option.

I appreciate any of your tries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really into jQuery but if I get your code right, the command `$(window).load()` is ought to initialize the preloading process. 
Yet it is only invoked when the page has already completely loaded (including all images). 
See https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ for reference.

I found a very simple example for preloading images for you:
http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/preload-images-with-jquery-preload-plugin/

Maybe these out-of-the-box-like jQuery image preload examples are also helpful for you:
jquery4u.com/plugins/preload-image-plugins/